# Got CUDA error CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE at Alea.CUDA.DeviceMemory.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

Tags: c#, aleagpu

I've been trying out the Alea CUDA examples and have been trying many configurations to make Alea happy.  I finally got the CUDNN minst test to work except it is giving me the following error while attempting to dispose device memory:

```
D:\AleaGPUTutorial-master\release>Tutorial.Cs.exe ExamplesCUDNNMnistTest
Classifying....
Performing forward propagation...
Finished forward propagation.
Classification Complete.

Performing forward propagation...
Finished forward propagation.
Classification Complete.

Performing forward propagation...
Finished forward propagation.
Classification Complete.


==========================================================

Result of Classification: 1, 3, 5
Test Passed!!

==========================================================

Done.
Got CUDA error CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Alea.CUDA.CUDAInterop.cuSafeCall(cudaError_enum result)
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$Engine.f@1-46[T](WorkerContext this, FSharpFunc`2 f, Unit _arg6)
   at Alea.CUDA.WorkerContext.eval[T](FSharpFunc`2 f)
   at Alea.CUDA.DeviceMemory.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
Got CUDA error CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Alea.CUDA.CUDAInterop.cuSafeCall(cudaError_enum result)
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$Engine.f@1-46[T](WorkerContext this, FSharpFunc`2 f, Unit _arg6)
   at Alea.CUDA.WorkerContext.eval[T](FSharpFunc`2 f)
   at Alea.CUDA.DeviceMemory.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
Got CUDA error CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Alea.CUDA.CUDAInterop.cuSafeCall(cudaError_enum result)
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$Engine.f@1-46[T](WorkerContext this, FSharpFunc`2 f, Unit _arg6)
   at Alea.CUDA.WorkerContext.eval[T](FSharpFunc`2 f)
   at Alea.CUDA.DeviceMemory.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
Got CUDA error CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Alea.CUDA.CUDAInterop.cuSafeCall(cudaError_enum result)
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$Engine.f@1-46[T](WorkerContext this, FSharpFunc`2 f, Unit _arg6)
   at Alea.CUDA.WorkerContext.eval[T](FSharpFunc`2 f)
   at Alea.CUDA.DeviceMemory.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

D:\AleaGPUTutorial-master\release>
```

I installed CUDA toolkit 7.5 and cudnn libs 6.2 -v2

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Alea do you use?

Comment: I'm using Alea.CUDA 2.2.0.3307

Comment: Please try Alea GPU V3 or also Alea TK www.aleatk.com, which is open source and shows how to use cuDNN for some DNN training